# CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes to a CIImage quickly

Tags: ios, xcode, core-image

I'm looking for an example of the `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes()` function in `iOS`?

I have a C-style array of 32BGRA pixels and am looking to quickly create a `CIImage` without copying them. My solution would tentatively involve `int* -> CVPixelBuffer -> CIImage.`

If there is a better way, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
+ (CIImage *)imageWithBitmapData:(NSData *)d bytesPerRow:(size_t)bpr size:(CGSize)size format:(CIFormat)f colorSpace:(CGColorSpaceRef)cs
```

(Full URL: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIImage/imageWithBitmapData:bytesPerRow:size:format:colorSpace:)

It seems that this method might do the trick! I'm not exactly sure what data format your C style array is, however, so proceed slowly with this one. It looks like your data needs to be in this format (according to the docs)

```
kCIFormatARGB8
A 32 bit-per-pixel, fixed-point pixel format.
```

Comment: That looks useful. However, how do I get the int* into NSData*? There doesn't seem to be an init class method I can send. Is NSData some sort of pointer-wrapper?

Comment: NSData is an objective-c object that just holds bytes. I'd suggest using '+ (id)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length'. Make sure you cast your int array to a (const void *). I think this should work since Ints are 32 bit. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Another thing. If you're looking to do it without copying, this other method might be better. (The link might not work, but the method is called dataWithBytesNoCopy:length: )http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytesNoCopy:length: